# ASP.NET MVC3 DropDownListFor force selected item when an item has Value = 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, selecteditem, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedvalue

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3
I need to create a DropDownList with 4 values :

- Don't mind
- 0
- 1
- 2 or +

with "Don't mind" as selected item.

Here is my code :

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListAnimals()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Don't mind", Value = "-1", Selected = true });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "0" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2 or +", Value = "2" });

        return items;
    }
```

and I use it like this in my view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AnimalNumber, new SelectList(Animal.ListAnimals() , "Value", "Text"))
```

With this code, the selected item is always "0" whereas it should be "Don't mind" as I explicitly write it.
BUT
when : `items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "0" });`
became : `items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0", Value = "[Anything but 0]" });`
it perfectly works and "Don't mind" is correctly selected.

So, I think MVC automatically select item where `Value = "0"`, in spite of the keyword `Selected`... How can I override it ? I really need to let `Value = "0"`, and I'm sure we can override this behavior.
Do someone know how ?

(BTW, I know my question [is very close of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235229/dropdownlistfor-with-an-item-value-0-always-selected) but the answers given in this thread don't satisfy me. I don't want to write my DDL in HTML because I'll loose the binding between my value and my model, and writing a jQuery script to change the selected value is "a little bit hacky".)
Do any proper way exists ?

Comment: What's the Model in your View? Can you post your Model?

Comment: Also, post your Controller Action.

Comment: My model has an int property called AnimalNumber. I just try to delcare it as an int? and ... the problem is solved ! But WHY ?? Is there any proper way to declare the property as int (and not int? ) and force my selected item not to be the one with `Value="0"`

Comment: That's because 0 is the default value for int. You can start you SelectListItem values from 1.

Comment: I thought the keyword `Selected` could override this behavior. So you don't know any other way to force an my selected item not to be the one with `Value="0"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the strongly-typed html helper for a DropDownList (`Html.DropDownListFor`), the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is overwritten by the value of your Model Property. It makes sense. So, when you use the Html Helper like below, the selected value will be `Model.AnimalNumber`. Since, the default value for an `int` is 0, when you create a new Model, and send it to your View, the value of its `int` properties are defaulted to 0. So, in this case, `Model.AnimalNumber` is 0, and therefore, the selected value of the DropDownList is the item with the value of 0.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AnimalNumber, Animal.ListAnimals())
```

In order to solve that issue, you can either change the type of your property to `int?` or you can make sure that the value of none of your `SelectListItem`s is 0, or you can set a default value for your property (in this case `AnimalNumber = -1`).

Comment: I just tried, but in this case, the default value is selected : "0" if the property is `int`, null if the property is `int?` ...

Comment: Your two first solutions are working, I will choose one of them, thank you very much