# MVC DropDownListFor default value for bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, boolean, dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlistfor with True/False values.  I want the default value to be true. Right now it's false because the default of a bool is false.  This dropdown sometimes gets created dynamically in javascript so I can't set the value in the model before it gets passed.  How do I set the default to True in the chtml file?

Thank you.

```
//----------  cshtml file ---------------
...
   <td class="valuebool">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IsBoolFilterCondition, 
        new SelectList(
            new[]
            {
                // The following two lines defaulted to false
                //new { Value = "true", Text = "True" },
                //new { Value = "false", Text = "False" },

                // The next two lines also defaulted to false
                //new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "True", Selected = true },
                //new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "False", Selected = false },

                // The following two lines also default to false
                new { Value = "true", Text = "True", Selected = true },
                new { Value = "false", Text = "False", Selected = false },                    
            },
            "Value",
            "Text"
            ),
            new { @class="valuebool"}
        )
...

//------- Model Class ------------------------
public class FilterCondition
{
      ...
      public bool IsBoolFilterCondition { get; set; }
      ...
}
```

//--------------- Browser Source -----------------------

    True
    False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IsBoolFilterCondition, 
        new SelectList(
            new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "True" ,Selected = true},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "False" },
            },
            "Value",
            "Text"
            ),
            new { @class="valuebool"}
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Malkam, unfortunately when I add ", Selected = true" to my SelectList, I get this error  error CS0826: No best type found for implicitly-typed array

Comment: Set Selected in SelectListItem as above

Comment: Sorry. My comment was unclear.  I did put the ", Selected = true" in the SelectedItem CTOR, just as you show above. When I did this, I get the error "No best type found for implicitly-typed array".              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IsBoolFilterCondition, 
        new SelectList(
            new[]
            {
                new { Value = "true", Text = "True", Selected = true },
                new { Value = "false", Text = "False" },
            },
            "Value",
            "Text"
            ),
            new { @class="valuebooldll"}
        )

Comment: Set Selected=false for second one

Comment: I put selected = false and it now compiles and runs, but it still defaults to false.  Any other ideas :      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IsBoolFilterCondition, 
        new SelectList(
            new[]
            {
                new { Value = "true", Text = "True", Selected = true },
                new { Value = "false", Text = "False", Selected = false },
            },
            "Value",
            "Text"
            ),
            new { @class="valuebooldll"}
        )

Comment: I still need a way to set the bool default value to true.  Anyone?

Comment: I hope IsBoolFilterCondition is of type boolean. As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235229/dropdownlistfor-with-an-item-value-0-always-selected,always false is selected as boolen default value is false.To work around make IsBoolFilterCondition nullable boolean type i.e bool? or change SelectListItem values to "1"/"0" instead of "true"/"false". I'm updating my solution with "1"/"0". See if it works for you.

Comment: Setting values to 1 and 0 works.  Of course I can no longer bind to a bool type, but I can bind to an int and use the int to set a bool value in the controller action method.   I am marking your solution as the answer.  Thank you very much for your help.  But if you know of a better way of handling the data binding to an int vs bool I would like to hear of it.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value?noredirect=1#comment36607172_23799091