# @Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownbox

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
       { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="True"},
         new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"}})
```

In view I am using this drop dowenlist coding. I run my application default deactive value is display in dropdown list box. I want display default **Active**

Comment: I hope Status is of type boolean.By default ddl value set to "Deactivate" as boolean default value is "false". Either make Status optional or convert it type to int and set values as 1/0 instead of true/false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610941/mvc-dropdownlistfor-default-value-for-bool/

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
           { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
             new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"}}) It is working correct

Comment: This code only pass the value false only

Comment: Eshan's solution working fine right?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
       { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="True"},
         new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"}},"Select One")
```

If you want Active to be selected by default then use `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
           { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="True",Selected=true},
             new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"}},"Select One")
```

If using `SelectList`, then you have to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725507%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and specify `SelectListItem` `Value` property which you want to set selected:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.title, 
                     new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem { Text = "Active" , Value = "True"},
      new SelectListItem { Text = "InActive", Value = "False" }
  },
    "Value", // property to be set as Value of dropdown item
    "Text",  // property to be used as text of dropdown item
    "True"), // value that should be set selected of dropdown
     new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I think it' wont work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610941/mvc-dropdownlistfor-default-value-for-bool/

Comment: I tested it on my system first then posted

Comment: @malkam I used 0 and 1 instead of true/false and it worked but whenever I submit the form, the value sent is **False** even if I try to send true/1. Help me out

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: ok, actually I've overlooked. I've used SelectList,but you're using List<SelectListItem>.

Comment: yes you are right i also just noticed

Comment: Its the value of the `Status` property that determines what is selected. Internally the method builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property. Setting `Selected=true` in the `SelectListItem` or `SelectList` constructor is ignored when binding to a mdoel.

Comment: if the model property contains no value, what about that case?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad. Then the first option will be selected (because something has to be). And ditto if the value of the property does not match one of the option values.

Comment: None of this worked for me. I had to make sure my equivalent of model.title was set to true by default, since that's what the selection is bound to.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me perfectly.

Comment: what about asp-items and a value when list is empty

Answer (score 5):

`SelectListItem` has a `Selected` property. If you are creating the `SelectListItem`s dynamically, you can just set the one you want as `Selected = true` and it will then be the default.

```
SelectListItem defaultItem = new SelectListItem()
{
   Value = 1,
   Text = "Default Item",
   Selected = true
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserName, new List<SelectListItem> 
   { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="True",Selected =true },
     new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Items, new List<SelectListItem>
   { new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="False"},
     new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="True",  Selected = true},
     })
```