# How to set a default value in a DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I've been working on this for 2 days and I can't make it work. I'm trying to make a DropDownListFor with a default value (Like in an Edit page). I made it work without a model but when there is a model, it shows the first item as the default not the one I wanted.
I tried adding a Selected = true in a SelectListItem while being in a foreach loop like this, still not working:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListCategories = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var item in listCategories)
{
    if(item.Id == Model.Category.Id)
    {
        selectListCategories.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name, Selected=true });
    }
    else
    {
        selectListCategories.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name });
    }
}
```

This one worked but without a model.

I also tried adding a default value in the SelectList object like that :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListingCategories, "Id", "Name", Model.Category.Id))
```

It either didn't work or there is something I didn't understand correctly because I tried adapting some example I saw here and on msdn posts without any success.

`ViewBag.ListingCategories` contains a IEnumerable list of my categories taken from my database.

Of course, `Model.Category` contains a Category object with an Id (this is a Foreign Key to another table) and a Name.

Now I'm out of option so hopefully I can find help here.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that `Model.Category.Id` holds a value? and if so, that it holds a value which is inside `ViewBag.ListingCategories` ? I suggest you post here more of your view code.

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value) (by @Elad Lachmi):

> SelectListItem has a Selected property. If you are creating the
>   SelectListItems dynamiclly, you can just set the one you want as
>   Selected = true and it will be the default.

```
SelectListItem defaultItem = new SelectListItem()
{
   Value = 1,
   Text = "Deafult Item",
   Selected = true
};
```