# Removing duplicates from a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that is returning duplicates. I don't know why it is returning duplicates.
Here is the control for my dropdown.

```
    @Html.DropDownList("procDateId", Model.GetEmpHoursDateRange.EmphoursdateSelectList, Model.GetEmpHoursDateRange.selectedEmplhoursdate, new { id = "procDateId" })
```

I want to be able to remove the duplicates once the page load.
I tested the code below with an alert and am able to get to the document.ready

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

            alert("here you go !!!");

            [].slice.call($('#procDateId').option)
              .map(function (a) {
                  if (this[a.innerText]) {
                      $('#procDateId'.option).removeChild(a);
                  } else {
                      this[a.innerText] = 1;
                  }
              }, {});

        });
```

Here is the html that my dropdown is rendering.

```
    <select id="procDateId" name="procDateId">
     <option value>1/11/2017</option>
     <option value>1/11/2017</option>
     <option value>1/10/2017</option>
     <option value>1/9/2017</option>
    </select>
```

The duplicates are not been removed with my code above. No luck. Kindly assist.

Comment: Your duplicates are coming from `Model.GetEmpHoursDateRange.EmphoursdateSelectList` and/or `Model.GetEmpHoursDateRange.selectedEmplhoursdate`. Why not fix at the source

Comment: No it is not coming from the source. I checked that. It duplicates once it renders on the page. I have spend a lot of time on it and unable to figure out what is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector for the option appears incorrect: `$('#procDateId').option` --> `('#procDateId option')`

Additionally, you can call `remove` on the option directly

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/db9zczr0/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the double up is you're using an overload with the `defaultOption` = `Model.GetEmpHoursDateRange.EmphoursdateSelectList`. The value returned is the duplicate.

> The default option appears at the start of the list and its value is
>   empty. A default option is used to communicate that no option is being
>   chosen from the list, such as when the drop-down control represents an
>   optional parameter.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548012(v=vs.111).aspx

So you will want to use a different overload, e.g.

> HtmlHelper.DropDownList Method (String, IEnumerable,
>   Object)

Then to tell the View to show the selected option using the saved session value, in the controller loop over the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set `Selected = true` for the matching item.

Comment: I'd go with this overload to remove the duplicate - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537935(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I want to be able to have a default selected value. On the load of the page, I want the first item in the dropdown to be the default value. Users of the application can navigate to other pages but when they return to this page I want the value they selected before leaving the page to be the current value. I am using session variable but the dropdownlist selected value has been a problem.

Comment: Then use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value to set the item as `selected`.  As you can see in your current output in your question including a default option doesn't mark it with the `selected` attribute

Comment: The link you sent me shows hardcoded data. It doesnt really show model data.

Comment: Your model data would be a collection of `SelectListItem`s, with one of them `SelectListItem{Text="1/11/2017", Value="1/11/2017", Selected=true}`

Comment: `public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}`

Comment: This is exactly how I did it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133044/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-user2320476).

Comment: Expanded answer from our discussion in chat