# How to set default value from drop down list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to set default value to PdvId = 3. I have five values in my IznosPdvSelectList and I want that on Id = 3

```
@Html.DropDownListFor
 (x => x.Nabava.PdvId,
 Model.Nabava.IznosPdvSelectList,
 "...",
 new { @class = "js-select2", id = "ddlIznosPdv"})
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799134/1232818

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor (x => x.Nabava.PdvId, Model.Nabava.IznosPdvSelectList, "...", new { @class = "js-select2", id = "ddlIznosPdv", Value=3})
```