# Set value for SelectList option label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Drop Down List in my MVC application, which is populated from my "PropertyList" model.

I have set the propertyList variable as follows to obtain the details needed for each option as follows;

```
var propertyList = new SelectList(Model.propertyList, "fullPropertyDetail", "FullAddress");

@Html.DropDownList("addresslist", (SelectList)propertyList, "-- Please select an address from the list below --", new { @id = "valid-addresslist" })
```

This populates the list as expected and the default option reads "-- Please select an address from the list --", however the value for that option is set as "".

Is there any way I can set the default option value as "none" as another system looks for this value if it is selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value)

Comment: @andtodd `Is there any way I can set the default option value as "none"` means? Please make it clear.

Comment: The default option displayed to the customer is "-- Please select an address from the list below --", i.e. that is the text they see, however the value of that item is set as "" (blank) and I need that value set as "none".

Comment: Okay! got it. Please check my answer. it will work for you

Comment: Use my updated answer. I have made a mistake with `IsSelected` instead of `Selected`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can do as follows:

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = propertyList.ToList();
   selectListItems.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select", Value = "none", Selected = true }));
}
@Html.DropDownList("addresslist", selectListItems, new { @id = "valid-addresslist" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `"-- Please select ..... below --"`option as `SelectListItem` in the `propertyList` `List`.

Like: `new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Please select ..... below --", Value = "none"}`