# preselect dropdown list razor page

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have the below code that I use to populate my dropdown in my Razor Page
I want to preselect a description - the "Value" of that needs to be set is found in

> s.UserEstablishmentId

How can I preselect this on the dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpEstablishments",
                    getEstablishments().Select(s => new SelectListItem()
                        {

                          Text = s.Description,
                          Value = s.EstablishId.ToString()
                      }),
                     new
                     {
                         @class = "dropdown form-control"
                     })
```

Comment: Take a look at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value you can find your answer here.

Comment: thats using preset options Im taking min from a database - finding it difficult to extrapolate from those examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using linq to create a new `SelectListItem` for `getEstablishments` element. When creating each instance of a `SelectListItem()` you need to determine if `Selected` should be `true` or `false`. Simply replace `YourConditionForSelectionHere` with a method that returns a `bool` or syntax that returns a `bool`, shown below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpEstablishments",
                    getEstablishments().Select(s => new SelectListItem()
                        {
                          Selected = (YourConditionForSelectionHere),
                          Text = s.Description,
                          Value = s.EstablishId.ToString()
                      }),
                     new
                     {
                         @class = "dropdown form-control"
                     })
```

Answer (score 0):

in the end something like this worked

```
 Selected= (s.UserEstablishmentId==s.EstablishId)? true:false,
```