# Selecte default value in dropdown list and pass id MVC drop-down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, dropdown, html-select

i used value the model for drop down list,

```
> public class Items
>     {
>         public int itemcategoryid { get; set; }
>         public string itemcategory { get; set; }
>         public int Itemsubcategoryid { get; set; }
>         public string Itemsubcategoryname { get; set; }
>     }
```

and below the code for controller

```
>             ItemViewModel catVM = new ItemViewModel();
>             List<Items> catlist = catVM.GetCategoryInfo();
>             ViewBag.categorylist = catlist;
```

After binding drop down list using below the  HTML code, the drop down list has populated and select default name as itemcategory but did not pass id of itemcategory  pass only itemcategory name   for POST.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.categorylist, "itemcategory", "itemcategory",  Model.itemcategory))
```

if i using below the HTML Code their pass value but did not select default name

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.categorylist, "itemcategoryid", "itemcategory", Model.itemcategory))
```

using below the code for retrieve data

> ```
> using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PS_Category", conn))
>                 {
>                     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>                     conn.Open();
>                     OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>                     while (reader.Read())
>                     {
>                         Items listitems = new Items(); ;
>                         listitems.itemcategoryid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CATID"]);
>                         listitems.itemcategory = reader["CATNAME"].ToString();
>                         items.Add(listitems);
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

Actually i want to to select default name and pass their id how can possible it??

Comment: Will you include the code of the function `catVM.GetCategoryInfo();`?

Comment: this is code for data retrieve  from database, and also edited my question and include this code

Comment: Oh, okay. I understood your question just now, you want to select the default value. What is the class you are using for `model` in the view?

Comment: Is model.itemcategory the id or the name in your model class?

Comment: my model class @model Webapps8.Models.Items , itemcategory is  name,  and itemcategoryid is id,

Comment: Just curious, why are you using model.itemcategory in your DropdownListFor— when you mentioned you should be passing the id? Shouldnt it be model.itemCategoryId?

Comment: i used both itemcategoryid and i itemcategory in model,  actually i need select itemcategory  as default value and pass id of itemcategory  which are named itemcategoryid

Comment: this code i used for edit  function, when i clicked edit drop down list retrieve data from db  and populate ,,

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here before but some are reporting that it doesn't work for them;
[@Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value)

---

If that doesn't work, the selectlist class documentation is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_

It is mentioned there that the constructor you used uses the last parameter as the selected value, hence you should do; (pass model.itemcategoryid in the end)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.categorylist, "itemcategoryid", "itemcategory", Model.itemcategoryid))
```

---

If the above answer doesn't work for you, here's another way but using jquery;

1. Add a class htmlattribute `selectLoop`;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemcategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.categorylist, "itemcategoryid", "itemcategory"), new { @class="selectLoop" })
```

2. Add this script to your view;

```
@section scripts{
 <script>
 // when the document is ready (server is done loading)
 $(document).ready(function(){

   // loop through all those with selectLoop class
   $(".selectLoop").each(function(){

      // get the selected value and store to variable
      var selected = "@Model.itemCategoryId";

      // loop through all the option inside the select
      $(this).find("option").each(function(){

         // check if the value attribute matches the selected variable
         if($(this).attr("value") == selected){

            // if match, assign the option's selected attribute to true
            $(this).attr("selected",true);
         }
      });
   });
 });
 </script>
}
```

Then in your shared/layout.cshtml, add `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` after jquery and bootstrap. See below;

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203136/discussion-on-answer-by-jerdine-sabio-selecte-default-value-in-dropdown-list-and).

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple dropdown Value You Use It.For Insert Value

```
ViewBag.DocumentId = new SelectList(_documentCategoryService.GetAll().OrderBy(a => a.Name), "Id", "Name");
```

For Edit You Can Use this.

```
ViewBag.DocumentId = new MultiSelectList(_documentCategoryService.GetAll(), "Id", "Name", _documentCategoryService.GetAllByExportId((int)id).Select(a => a.DocumentCategoryId).ToArray());
```

View Part:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Documents Require</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.DropDownList("DocumentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @placeholder = "Select Documents", @class = "span6 chzn-select documentCategories", @tabindex = "8", @multiple = "multiple", @name = "DocumentId" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

For Single DropdownValue.

```
ViewBag.BranchId = new SelectList(_branchService.GetAllByOrganizationId((User as CustomPrincipal).DefaultOrganizationId), "Id", "Name");


ViewBag.BranchId = new SelectList(_branchService.GetAllByOrganizationId((User as CustomPrincipal).DefaultOrganizationId), "Id", "Name", exportLetter.LcTransctionDetails.Transactions.BranchId);

<div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Branch</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.DropDownList("BranchId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Branches" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What is   _documentCategoryService?

Comment: This is my Project service. Here you put your model data.like as dbContext then table name