# How to set default value for a model property which is displayed in a @Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

```
 @model ProjectName.Models.ViewModel
 var abc = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["abc"];
```

The `abc` stores all retrieved records and then it displays them via the following html tag:

```
@Html.DropDownList("abcID", abc , "Select abc ", new { @class = "form-control",  required = "required" })
```

I need to set default value for `abcId` inside the `@Html.DropDownList`. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi,@jamali khan.Is my solution worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value),Here is a demo worked:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult SendReport()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listAdmin = new List<SelectListItem>();

            listAdmin.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "admin1",
                Value = "1"
            });
            listAdmin.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "admin2",
                Value = "2"
            });
            ViewBag.listAdmin = listAdmin;
            //ViewData["listAdmin"] = listAdmin;
            Admin admin = new Admin { id = "2", name = "admin2" };
            return View(admin);
        }
```

Admin.cs:

```
public class Admin
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

View：

```
@model Admin
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SendReport";
}

<h1>View</h1>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.id, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listAdmin, "Value", "Text", Model.id), "Selecte", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
</div>
```

Result:
[image]