# How can I pass the URL value into my combobox?

Tags: c#, html, parameters, model, dropdownlistfor

I have the following URL: `https://localhost:27635/Student/Create?PersonId=1`

I also have a combobox filled with Persons which the user can use to select a Person. How can I set the combobox to have by default the PersonId from the URL?

This is the combobox code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.PersonId,
    new SelectList(Model.Persons, "Id", "Fullname", Model.PersonId),
    "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

It contains PersonIds, displaying the full name.
The reason I want to use a combobox instead of saving the value from the URL directly is because I want to allow the user to change.

Another thing im curious about is if its possible to have the default `-- Select --` show up if the URL id is incorrect and not in the combobox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hello you can properly use something like the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799134/10293281)

basically there is an overload to the `SelectList` function you can find it in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

so `SelectList` will take following

**items (IEnumerable)** - The items used to build each `SelectListItem` of the list.

**dataValueField (String)** - The data value field. Used to match the `Value` property of the corresponding `SelectListItem`.

**dataTextField (String)** - The data text field. Used to match the `Text` property of the corresponding `SelectListItem`.

**dataGroupField (String)** - The data group field. Used to match the `Group` property of the corresponding `SelectListItem`.

**selectedValue (Object)** - The selected value. Used to match the `Selected` property of the corresponding `SelectListItem`.

here is an example:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.CountryId, // Specifies where to store selected country Id
                      // It needs to be null for the default selection to work!

    new SelectList(Model.Countries, // IEnumerable<Country>, contains all countries loaded from a database
                   "Id",   // Use Country.Id as a data source for the values of dropdown items
                   "Name", // Use Country.Name as a data source for the text of dropdown items
                   13 // Specifies Australia (which has ID of 13) as the element selected by default
                   ),

    // Text of option that prompts user to select
    "- Please select your country -"
)
```

Comment: you can replace the default value with something like Request.QueryString["PersonId"]