# DropDownListFor value default

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have the following code, and I need it to have a default value.
`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m =\> m.Articulo.CategoriaId, Model.ListaCategorias,
"Seleccione una categoría", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

`
is simple no?

My intention is to achieve a default value, but I have this dropdown list and I don't know much about C#, if I can at least achieve a default value, I'll be fine.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value

Comment: thanks, I'll see it there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Html.DropDownListFor how to set default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799091/html-dropdownlistfor-how-to-set-default-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `@foreach` to check which option you want to be the selected one:

```
<select asp-for="Articulo.CategoriaId" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Seleccione una categoría</option>
    @foreach (var item in l)
    {
        if (item.xxx=="xxx")
        {
            <option selected value=@item.xxx>@item.xxx</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value=@item.xxx>@item.xxx</option>
        }

    }
</select>
```